# Django scaling and saving forms with inheritance

Tags: python, django, forms, inheritance, modelform

I am quite new to Django. I am currently using ModelForm to save user input data to model. However, I would like to save data to other child models which inherits from parent model. However, my code saves data to the parent model. I guess that save() function should be overwritten to save data to child model, but I have no idea how to do it. Also, how should I scale my template or forms.py to include more forms with different submit button names(or any other method so that submitted forms could be distinguished and database populated accordingly)? Any insights highly appreciated. Please find my code below.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions, Scenario1_Assumptions,
Scenario2_Assumptions, Scenario3_Assumptions, Scenario4_Assumptions ... 
Scenario_N_Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Assumptions
    fields = ['Worst_Case', 'Grey_Case', 'Red_Case', 'Blue_Case', 
              'Green_Case', 'Best_Case']
    exclude = ()

AssumptionsFormSet = modelformset_factory(Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, 
extra = 5)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  AssumptionsFormSet, modelformset_factory
from .models import Scenario1_Assumptions, Assumptions


def get_assumptions(request):




if request.method == 'POST':

    formset = AssumptionsFormSet(request.POST)

    if formset.is_valid():

        if 'scenario1' in request.POST:

            for form in formset:

               Scenario1_Assumptions =  form.save() #THIS DOESN'T WORK

        if 'scenario2' in request.POST:

             for form in formset:

                 Scenario2_Assumptions =  form.save() #and so on...

else:
    formset = AssumptionsFormSet()


return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Grey_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Red_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Blue_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Green_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Scenario1_Assumptions(Assumptions):
    pass

class Scenario2_Assumptions(Assumptions):
    pass

class Scenario3_Assumptions(Assumptions):
    pass

class Scenario4_Assumptions(Assumptions):
    pass
.
.
.
class Scenario_N_Assumptions(Assumptions):
    pass
```

Assumptions.html

```
<form action="" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
<table id="formset" class="form">
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
<thead><tr>
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr></thead>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<td>
{# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
{% if forloop.first %}
  {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
  {{ field }}
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<input type="submit", name = "scenario1", value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach anyway. What's the point of all those separate tables? Why wouldn't you have a single model with a `scenario_number` field?

Comment: Highly likely, since I am new to Django. How would your approach work? Would it be possible to transfer all the data from database into pandas.Dataframe and to distinguish them later?